# python: Invalid XML string

Tags: python, xml, prestashop-1.6

I am encoding an xml to send it to a website using `urllib.urlencode()`. But I am getting the response from the server as incorrect xml string. Any idea how do I fix the issue? How do I validate the xml string?

Here is the xml:

```
discount="""<prestashop xmlns:ns0="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<specific_price>
    <id>200</id>
    <id_shop_group>0</id_shop_group>
    <id_shop>0</id_shop>
    <id_cart>0</id_cart>
    <id_product ns0:href="http://www.cacciatoreshop.it/api/products/1036">1036</id_product>
    <id_product_attribute>0</id_product_attribute>
    <id_currency>0</id_currency>
    <id_country>0</id_country>
    <id_group>0</id_group>
    <id_customer>0</id_customer>
    <id_specific_price_rule>0</id_specific_price_rule>
    <price>-1.000000</price>
    <from_quantity>1</from_quantity>
    <reduction>27.620000</reduction>
    <reduction_tax>1</reduction_tax>
    <reduction_type>amount</reduction_type>
    <from>0000-00-00 00:00:00</from>
    <to>0000-00-00 00:00:00</to>
</specific_price>
</prestashop>"""

print(urllib.urlencode({'xml': discount}))
> xml=%3Cprestashop+xmlns%3Ans0%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2Fxlink%22%3E%0A%09%3Cspecific_price%3E%0A%09%09%3Cid%3E200%3C%2Fid%3E%0A%09%09%3Cid_shop_group%3E0%3C%2Fid_shop_group%3E%0A%09%09%3Cid_shop%3E0%3C%2Fid_shop%3E%0A%09%09%3Cid_cart%3E0%3C%2Fid_cart%3E%0A%09%09%3Cid_product+ns0%3Ahref%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cacciatoreshop.it%2Fapi%2Fproducts%2F1036%22%3E1036%3C%2Fid_product%3E%0A%09%09%3Cid_product_attribute%3E0%3C%2Fid_product_attribute%3E%0A%09%09%3Cid_currency%3E0%3C%2Fid_currency%3E%0A%09%09%3Cid_country%3E0%3C%2Fid_country%3E%0A%09%09%3Cid_group%3E0%3C%2Fid_group%3E%0A%09%09%3Cid_customer%3E0%3C%2Fid_customer%3E%0A%09%09%3Cid_specific_price_rule%3E0%3C%2Fid_specific_price_rule%3E%0A%09%09%3Cprice%3E-1.000000%3C%2Fprice%3E%0A%09%09%3Cfrom_quantity%3E1%3C%2Ffrom_quantity%3E%0A%09%09%3Creduction%3E27.620000%3C%2Freduction%3E%0A%09%09%3Creduction_tax%3E1%3C%2Freduction_tax%3E%0A%09%09%3Creduction_type%3Eamount%3C%2Freduction_type%3E%0A%09%09%3Cfrom%3E0000-00-00+00%3A00%3A00%3C%2Ffrom%3E%0A%09%09%3Cto%3E0000-00-00+00%3A00%3A00%3C%2Fto%3E%0A%09%3C%2Fspecific_price%3E%0A%09%3C%2Fprestashop%3E
```

How do I check what is wrong here? Is there any function to check the validity?

Thanks.

Comment: The XML looks okay. How do you send it to the server? Show your code.

Comment: @Tomalak I am using this module https://github.com/guewen/prestapyt/blob/master/prestapyt/prestapyt.py .Line no: 283.

Comment: are you encoding before sending it to server then you have to force the same encoding in the parser

Comment: @CY5 parser on the server side?

Comment: or instead just decode XML  on server side before sending it to some function